# App Script for fetching Facebook post data and appended to a Google Sheet. But it keeps showing error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, facebook-graph-api

I have tried to use the below code to collect total impression and total reach for posts on facebook page with app script and google sheet. However, it keeps showing 'Error: Exception: Request failed for https://graph.facebook.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error":{"message":"(#100) The value must be a valid insights metric","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"Alk7ixUCpK2pVqWDGAFVLu3"}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)'

May I ask if anyone know what caused the issue please? thanks!

```js
function collectPostData() {
  var pageId = 'ID'; // Replace with your Facebook Page ID
  var accessToken = 'token'; // Replace with your Facebook Page access token

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  try {
    var posts = getPosts(pageId, accessToken);

    // Append headers to the sheet
    sheet.appendRow(['Post ID', 'Created Time', 'Message', 'Total Impressions', 'Total Reach']);

    // Iterate over each post
    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
      var post = posts[i];

      var impressions = getPostMetric(post.id, 'impressions', accessToken);
      var reach = getPostMetric(post.id, 'reach', accessToken);

      // Append post data to the sheet
      sheet.appendRow([post.id, post.created_time, post.message, impressions, reach]);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Error: ' + e);
  }
}

function getPostMetric(postId, metricName, accessToken) {
  var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/' + postId + '/insights?metric=' + metricName + '&access_token=' + accessToken;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  if (data.error) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch metric ' + metricName + ' for post ' + postId + ': ' + data.error.message);
  }

  return data.data[0].values[0].value;
}
```

Comment: I can't find any metric named `reach` mentioned anywhere on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v17.0/insights, and none named just `impressions` either.